# using splinter to navigate webpages, cannot get Browser

Tags: python, splinter

At first I tried the standard "from splinter import Browser" but I got the follwoing error:

```
    from splinter import browser
ImportError: No module named 'splinter'
```

now, I installed it via git, and ensured the dist-packages was created.  I've tried python 2.7 and 3.  Now lately, I'm using the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2 (get errors when changing to 3 as well)

import splinter

def navigate_to(web_page, how_long):
    b = splinter.Browser()
    b.visit(web_page)
```

which gives the following

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hw", line 30, in <module>
    navigate_to(platform_int, 60)
  File "./hw", line 23, in navigate_to
    b = splinter.Browser()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 49, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.3.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.3.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Help?!

Comment: `Exec format error` usually means you are try to run an 64 bit program on a 32 bit platform or vice versa. I think you downloaded the wrong version the webdriver. Can you show us how you installed Splinter?